# ActiveX Combo Box Selection Disappears After Selection

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex, activexobject

My VBA code works successfully when loading the combo box with different list based on a Selected Case. However, when I select an option from the drop down, the selection does not load into the Combo Box. The Combo Box goes blank.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub cbxTrainingSubject_DropButtonClick()

    cbxTrainingSubject.Clear

    Set shTables = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables")
    Set shForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
    Dim rng As Range

    Select Case cbxTrainingArea.Value
        Case "Assembly"
            Set rng = shTables.ListObjects("assemblyTraining").ListColumns("Assembly Training").DataBodyRange
            shForm.cbxTrainingSubject.List = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
        Case "Fabrication"
            Set rng = shTables.ListObjects("FabTraining").ListColumns("Fab Training").DataBodyRange
            shForm.cbxTrainingSubject.List = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Here is the Properties window for the target Combo Box:
[image: Combo Box Properties]

When I make a selection, the Combo Box stays blank.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what's going on?

Comment: Why not update `cbxTrainingSubject` when `cbxTrainingArea` is changed?  That might be more reliable.

Comment: @TimWilliams cbxTrainingSubject is dependent on cbxTrainingArea value selection . Can you share some suggested code to help me better understand?

Comment: If i am understanding the dilemma properly, I would remove the clear method at the beginning of the procedure. It isn't necessary when alternating lists anyways and might be clearing the value immediately after clicking as well. I would also check other events tied to that combo box to ensure they are not interfering.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to use `cbxTrainingArea_Change`

For example:

```vb
Private Sub cbxTrainingArea_Change()
    
    Dim wsTables As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    Set wsTables = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables")
    Select Case cbxTrainingArea.Value
        Case "Assembly": Set rng = wsTables.Range("Assembly")
        Case "Fabrication": Set rng = wsTables.Range("Fabrication")
    End Select
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        cbxTrainingSubject.List = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
    Else
        cbxTrainingSubject.Clear
    End If
    
End Sub
```